# Fully Closing a phonegap android app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

How do I fully close a PhoneGap Android app? I've tried using device.exitApp() as well as navigator.app.exitApp() and have the same problem with both.

The problem is that I have an html file, index.html, that links to an external html file, main.html. Now if I hit the close button without going to the external file, the app closes just fine. If I go to the external file and then go back to index then hit close, it closes index but brings up main. How do I completely close the app whether or not I go the external page?

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.html">Index</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Main.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.html">Index</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Android Manifest

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".TestActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: That's not how android works. You're probably opening a second instance of your activity.

Comment: What do you mean? The only activities that I have are the default one and the droidgap one so that external links can work. Without the droidgap activity, the external links doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was how PhoneGap Android worked with PhoneGap 1.0.0.

This behaviour has changed to more like what you are expecting in PhoneGap 1.1.0. Try upgrading.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/10/changes-in-phonegap-android-110.html

"Now when you are dealing with multiple page apps there is a change to navigator.app.exitApp(). This command now exits the app completely it does not return to the previous page. If you want to go back a page you should use navigator.app.backHistory()."

Comment: Just an additional note, until they fix it in 1.2.0, you must set the `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="2" />` to less than 5 (e.g.: 2) in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Thanks @Devgeeks.  I was using navigator.app.exitApp() which doesn't appear to be documented?  And it wasn't working.  The <uses-sdk /> of less than 5 worked for me.

Comment: Navarr: Good to hear, but 1.2.0 is out today so it's no longer needed if you can upgrade your project :)

Comment: Hi all, can any one tell me how can i use startActivity() and startActivityForResult() in case if i use phoneGap in my android app?